# Obtaining balloon memory statistics within a Linux vm (kvm)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel, kvm

Does anyone know how to obtain balloon memory statistics within a vm? I've scoured google, stack overflow, twitter, and the like.

I'm attempting to set up a monitor to pull the metric but I'm at a loss where the metric is located.  I would assume there is a metric somewhere...

Comment: something like that "virtio_balloon statiistics[, kvm memory ballooning]" : https://fossies.org/linux/qemu/docs/virtio-balloon-stats.txt ?

Comment: I was hoping for a simple mechanism for retrieving the information.  Oh well, I guess I'll have to write some code.

Comment: Looks like this can be done via the proxmox gui:  [link](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/memory-ballooning-on-alpine-linux.87952/#post-386196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MolbOrg directed me in the right direction.  Currently there is no simple method of pulling the metrics from within the VM without writing a program to extract the metrics from the QEMU Object Model.

Both `libvirt` and `proxmox` are able to obtain the metrics at the hypervisor level without too much trouble, see [here](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/memory-ballooning-on-alpine-linux.87952/#post-386196).

FYI: to force the balloon to action, set change the memory shares to say 0 or some other low value (default=1000). Be aware setting it to 0 will force the VM to decrease available memory to the minimum memory setting and may cause the kernel to panic if it is set too low.

Comment: You will need to wait a while, but please don't forget to drop back and [accept your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).